# Sonos API - Minimum segment length for programmed radio

Tags: sonos

Is there a minimum (segment) length of tracks a Sonos device needs to have for a programmed radio?

I now respond a GetMetadata request for a programmed radio with only 1 track to be more responsive to changes. But I have the impression the Sonos device then immediately asks for yet another track for the programmed radio. So I think the device needs at least 2 tracks.

Does anyone know if this is the case? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of programmed radio, the Sonos player will always request a segment of 100 tracks. Your service can return anywhere between 1 and 100 tracks in the response. We always need 3 tracks, so while you can return 1, we will always fetch another 2.

Generally speaking, returning more tracks in the response will result in the Sonos player making less frequent requests asking for the next segment. This decision is usually left to your service and business model. For example, if your service supports track ratings, then you could dynamically steer the content based on a user’s rating of the current track, and thus only have 3 tracks in a segment.

API reference http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/288

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this! I read the API Reference, but there's nothing there about the Sonos player needing 3 tracks for a programmed radio, only that you can choose the amount of tracks you return. So I assumed when I returned just 1 track, Sonos will ask song after song, so I could be highly responsive to changes in the programmed radio.